# Asking about map editors, where to ask?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

"Arqade" is a site where you ask for games, dudes and etc.

My question is about where I have to post a question related with game editors like "Badland's level creator (android)" or "Hammer world editor (for Valve games such as Portal series)".

So, when I want to post something related with "Hammer world editor" or "Badland's level creator", where I have to post it?

In "Game Developing"? Because world editors are aproximately like developing new levels or games (see "Portals through time" in example) like "Hammer world editor", but are quedtions about games that they has been developed yet.

So, the question is:

**If I want to post something related with game editors, where I have to post them? In *Arqade* or in *Game Developing*?**

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're on-topic on Game Dev. From their tour:

> Ask about...
>   game-specific programming issues (engine architecture, game-related APIs, networking, tools, etc)

That doesn't necessarily mean they're off-topic here but I'd recommend posting to GameDev. You'll get better answers there.

Note that GameDev do frown upon "how do I get started questions"- they want to solve specific problems.